# Can I get some advice for possibly getting more users from Israel/Palestine?

Tags: discussion, users, new-users

I'm a "returning expat" - an Israeli who lived in the Netherlands for a few years. The site was quite helpful for me over there, despite a relatively small number of users.

I have also found myself with expat-type questions regarding Israel now that I've come back - but there's practically nobody to answer them. Extremely few users, and I've provided the same number of up-voted answers as the other 3 top answerers *combined*. That's not good...

So: How would you advise someone who does not really spend time with expats, and is not a social media buff, to possibly help in "recruiting" more users to frequent the site - both to ask and to answer.

PS - I have a bunch of stuff I could definitely answer if anybody asked, but I don't feel like sitting around and inventing artificial questions.

Answer (score 4):

> I don't feel like sitting around and inventing artificial questions.

Why not? Creating and then self-answering questions are a perfectly valid thing to do on most of the StackExchange sites ([including Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)), and given your experience you might add very helpful information to the site. Once there are more questions about Israel and Palestine there will be more users coming to the site from the various search engines, driving traffic and hopefully creating more questions to answer, and answers themselves.

Comment: I could write an entire encyclopedia of things I know about life here. What should I write about though? Without someone telling me "XYZ is important to write about", I'd feel I'm just shouting at the storm.

Answer (score 2):

Consider looking at some of the top questions for other countries.  Often they'll be transferable.  If you have information for Israel/Palestine around those topics, you could ask/answer and drive some traffic related to those specifically.